# 16.10 Kubuntu Installer Crash

Tags: usb, kubuntu

I have tried several ways to get Kubuntu to install via USB but I am not having any luck. The install keeps crashing after I click continue on the prepare step. The HDD that I want to install to is empty. I have tied changing the BIOS/UEFI to allow for USB. Also changed to Rufus as installer. Checked the different boxes on the prepare step and didn't connect to wifi as well. The The USB is formatted to FAT32, is 16GB and since the iso is hybrid changed it to a DD image. Now the try mode still works internet, terminal even partition manager. Any advice would be appreciated.